# How to partition static data into multiple GPUs?

Tags: cuda, pthreads, gpu

I want to partition a large data set and split the work on multiple GPUs. I want to make these data static so that I don't have to load to GPU for the second run. Now the problem is that, pthread_create requires all input data be assembled into a "struct", and I am not sure whether assembling a bunch of static data into a struct will work. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What does `pthread_create` have to do with CUDA?

Comment: I hope there is another option, but Sanders's "CUDA by example" demonstrated a multiple GPU example by using pthread_create to create a new thread for a non-default GPU.

Comment: To use a non-default GPU, we have to create a new thread, right? Or simply call runtime "cudaSetDevice" will do it?

Comment: Since CUDA 4 was released, you don't need to use a separate host threads for multiple GPUs. You need to have a look at [this GTC presentation](http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php?sessionTopic=&searchByKeyword=paulius&submit=&select=+&sessionEvent=&sessionYear=&sessionFormat=#1451).

Comment: Great resources! A quick look of the powerpoint tells me that "cudaSetDevice" will make multiple GPUs run asynchronizingly, but will look into it later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "modern" CUDA multi-gpu, it is no longer necessary to use a different host thread to hold a context on a given device. Since CUDA 4.0, the API is thread safe, and one host thread can hold and work with multiple contexts simply using `cudaSetDevice`.

A really, really basic example of how to distribute a large dataset over multiple GPUs in CUDA 4.x or CUDA 5 could be as simple as:

```
int remainder = N;
int* plens = new int[ngpus];
float** pvals = new float*[ngpus];
float* source = &host_array[0];
for(int i=0; i<ngpus; i++) {
    const int blen = N/gpus;
    plens[i] = blen;
    remainder -= blen;
    if (remainder < blen) {
        plens[i] += remaninder;
        remainder = 0;
    }
    size_t sz = sizeof(float) * size_t(plens[i]);
    cudaSetDevice(i);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&pvals[i], sz);
    cudaMemcpy(pvals[i], source, sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    source += plens[i];
}
```

*[disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled or tested, use a own risk]*

assuming that the GPUs are sequentially numbered from [0,ngpus-1] and the source data is held in the floating point array `host_array` of length `N`. You get back an array of device pointers in `pvals` and the length of each array in `plens`. Note that each pointer is only valid in the context in which you allocated it, so make sure you select the device before using the pointer with a kernel launch or API call.

Comment: hi talonmies, how could we contact you?

Comment: excellent. I just thought you were interested in large scale real GPU applications

Comment: @flow: And indeed I am interested in such things. But I have no interest in being bombarded with unsolicited contact from complete strangers I have no professional or personal relationship with, which is precisely what would happen if I make my contact details available in an open forum like this one.

Comment: I understand perfectly your situation. If you are interested in contributing please email to werner.schroedinger@googlemail.com